# How to create query using Django Models with grouping , average and "IN"

Tags: python, django, django-models

Does anyone know how to build such raw query:

```
SELECT week_number, part, type,  AVG(col1), AVG(col2), AVG(col3), ( AVG(col1) + AVG(col2) + AVG(col3) ) as Total
FROM table1
WHERE location = 'TgR'
AND week_number BETWEEN 38 AND 42
AND part IN ('Q', 'F')
GROUP BY week_number, part, type
```

in Django model ? completely have no idea how to do this

My model:

```
class testTable(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField( verbose_name="Date" )
    week_number = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name="Week number")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Location")
    part = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Part")
    col1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Col1")
    col2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Col2")
    col3 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Col3")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.location)+'-'+str(self.date)+'-'+str(self.part)
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: can you add django model with query filter will help you

Comment: Model added. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Avg
from django.db.models import FloatField
query_set=testTable.objects.filter(location='TgR',\
          part__in=['Q', 'F'],week_number__lte=38,week_number__gte=42).\
          aggregate(col1_avg=Avg('col1'),col2_avg=Avg('col2'),col3_avg=Avg('col3'),\
          Total= (Avg('col1',output_field=FloatField())+Avg('col2', output_field=FloatField())+Avg('col3', output_field=FloatField()))
         )
```

from that above query set you can get the value,also refer the doc [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: thanks for the post
I am receiving following error : "unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'dict' and 'tuple'"

Comment: Do you know why ?

Comment: it was my mystake - everything is okay

Comment: but, I am receiving only one record, should be more

Comment: do you know why ?

Comment: Did you add MySQL results

Comment: I used annotate() function ( instead of aggregate ) and it's perfect