# Why am I receiving only one record during aggregation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I used code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120864/how-to-create-query-using-django-models-with-grouping-average-and-in/46122083#46122083) :

```
from django.db.models import Avg
from django.db.models import FloatField
query_set=testTable.objects.filter(location='TgR',\
          part__in=['Q', 'F'],week_number__lte=38,week_number__gte=42).\
      aggregate(col1_avg=Avg('col1'),col2_avg=Avg('col2'),col3_avg=Avg('col3'),\
      Total= (Avg('col1',output_field=FloatField())+Avg('col2', output_field=FloatField())+Avg('col3', output_field=FloatField()))
     )
```

but I am receiving only one record ( should be 20 ). It looks like django aggregates all records.

What I wanna do is execute this query using django model:

```
SELECT week_number, part, type,  AVG(col1), AVG(col2), AVG(col3), ( AVG(col1) + AVG(col2) + AVG(col3) ) as Total
FROM table1
WHERE location = 'TgR'
AND week_number BETWEEN 38 AND 42
AND part IN ('Q', 'F')
GROUP BY week_number, part, type
```

Comment: You can perform row queries for more information see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)

Comment: Are you sure you have `GROUP BY week_number, part, type` in the query? If you leave that out, you'll aggregate everything. I don't see where the answer in the other question does that, but I don't know Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate is supposed to return data based on all objects. If you want to get data per row, you should use `annotate()` instead.